# Imagemagick convert for pdf to jpg

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to convert pdf to jpg image using `imagemagic` converter. I have used below command to run this process. But when I run this through command line it works fine.  But when use php `exec` function to run same command it never works.

```
convert -density 200X200 -compose atop -geometry +2000+2000 "E:\VIEW_JPG\2200115244.pdf" -background White -layers flatten -resize 100%^> "E:\VIEW_JPG\2200115244_WM.jpg"
```

Comment: What is the error? Is there a reason why you're shelling out instead of using the PHP Imagick wrapper?

Comment: It never show errors. Only thing is when I run this command from command line it works fine. but when I use `exec()`  it did not work

Comment: I want to convert pdf file to jpg